# Using UNIX find to generate TAGS files when the $CWD contains a space or special character

Tags: unix, emacs, find, etag

The following UNIX one-liner looks for Python files below the CWD and adds them to a TAGS file for Emacs (or we could do the same with Ctags).

```
find . -name *.py -print | xargs etags
```

This breaks if the CWD has a space or other unusual character in its name. `-print0` or `-ls` don't seem to help, in spite of what `man find` says. Is there a neat way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 etags
```

should do the trick -- you need the `-0` arg to xargs to match the `-print0` properly.

**edit**

you probably need the quotes around `*.py` as well, if there are any .py files in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, and you were quite right about the quotes. D'OH!